# Trying to parse multiple htmls using dplyr and rvest. Need help simplifying with loops

Tags: r, loops, dplyr, rvest

I am trying to parse multiple urls and create a dataframe. Having trouble simplifying the code. Can someone guide me in putting everything in a loop?

I have 5 urls read into lists using **rvest::read_html** as follows:

```
list_1 <- read_html(url_1)
list_2 <- read_html(url_2)
list_3 <- read_html(url_3)
list_4 <- read_html(url_4)
list_5 <- read_html(url_5)
```

Next I'm running the following code to create a dataframe:

```
## Get data
ZipCode_1 <- list_1 %>% 
  html_nodes(".horizontal .horizontal .vertical .vertical .formfield:nth-child(1) .value") %>% 
  html_text()
Units_1 <- list_1 %>% 
  html_nodes(".horizontal .horizontal .vertical .vertical .formfield+ .formfield .value") %>% 
  html_text()
Size_1 <- listing_1 %>% 
  html_nodes(".horizontal .horizontal .horizontal+ .horizontal .formfield:nth-child(1) .value") %>% 
  html_text()
  
## Create dataframe
list_df_1 <- data.frame(ZipCode_1, Units_1, Size_1, stringsAsFactors = FALSE)

## Add this back to a main list
colnames(list_df_1) <- colnames(list_df)
list_df <- rbind(list_df, list_df_1)
```

Of course I have to do the above 5 times.
Anyway I am put this inside a loop? Something like:

```
for (i in 1:5) {
## above code block
}
```

I have tried a few variations of **paste()** and **assign()** trying to replace _1, _2, _3, etc. with '_i' but keep hitting a wall.

Help appreciated with learning the proper use.

Comment: can you please make a reprex?